Centered Binomial Distribution vs Fixed Weight Ternary Sampler
Fixed weight ternary polynomial vector sampler randomly selects a polynomial from ${R_q[x]}/{(x^n+1)}$ with coefficients $-1,1,0$. Notable KEMs that uses fixed weight ternary samplers include NTRU, LIZARD SMAUG-T etc.
On the other hand,  KEMs such as KYBER, SABER, NEW-HOPE uses Centered Binomial Distribution (CBD). The sampling technique of $CBD_\eta$ is given below. If we set $\eta=1$, it becomes a ternary polynomial sampler with hamming weight 0.5.

Is there any specific advantage of using fixed weight ternary sampler with respect to CBD with $\eta=1$. One advantage fixed weight ternary sampler  provides that it gives a freedom to set a hamming weight value as compared to $CBD_1$ where hamming weight is always equal to $0.5$
On the other hand, we noticed that CBD requires fewer hash calls (for random number generation) as compared to fixed weight ternary sampler.
It would be grateful if someone could provide more insight on this.

Could you please provide the reference for the picture ?

There are a couple of misconceptions here.
Firstly, the a Centred Binomial Distribution with $\eta=1$ has expected Hamming density 0.5. In particular, it is possible (although unlikely) that the CBD will return the all zeroes polynomial (Hamming weight/density 0). This would lead to a very weak instance of all of the various systems. More generally, very low Hamming weight/density polynomials lead to weaker instances, which fixed Hamming weight solutions avoid.
Secondly, the amount of random number generator calls is an implementation dependent characteristic. Most implementations of fixed Hamming weight methods use inefficient shuffling methods rather than the information theoretically optimal combinatorial number methods. If the best (though arguably more complicated) methods are used, fixed Hamming weight methods with $k$ +1 coefficients and $k$ -1 coefficients requires entropy
$$\log\left(\binom nk\binom{n-k}k\right)$$
whereas the CBD with $\eta=1$ would require entropy
$$\log 4^n.$$
Another property when working in rings mod $X^n-1$ is that balanced polynomials (such as those returned by fixed Hamming weight, balanced methods) do not reveal any information when projected down to the subring of polynomials mod $X-1$ as they all  project to the zero polynomial.

I am really thankful for providing your valuable insights. Could you please explain
how the entropy values are calculated? Please provide some reference if there are any.

Could you please provide some reference for efficient implementation of HWT. As of now, the only state of the art techniques that we know  is SampleinBall ( Fisher Yates Shuffling ). It uses 32+1 bits of randomness to generate one polynomial coefficient in contrast to CBD that uses only 4 bits to generate one polynomial coefficient.

@SwaminathanV Here's a related answer of mine that shows how to map from an integer uniformly selected from the $[0,\binom nk-1]$ to a collection of $k$ distinct positions in the range $[0,n-1]$.

Thanks for the link. I understood these calculations now. Since CBD has more entropy, what can I deduce from it? Is CBD better?

@SwaminathanV Although CBD requires Shannon entropy $n\log 4$ to generate using Algorithm 2, it only exhibits Shannon entropy $1.5n\log 2$ in output (again there are more entropy efficient, but more complicated ways to generate CBD). A higher min entropy is better against brute force guessing attacks, but CBD allows the possibility of low Hamming weight samples which are more vulnerable to other "weak key" attacks.
